# How to delete a row from JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` (`searchListTable`) and a want to delete a row from the table without using table Model. Also, I am fetching data in the `searchlist` from an XML.

Here is my code:

```
int selIndex[] = searchListTable.getSelectedRows();
if (selIndex != null) {
    searchListTable.removeRow(selIndex);
    keyValueTableModel.removeRows(selIndex);
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(searchListTable);
    searchListTable.clearSelection();
```

Please help..
How can I delete row from table?

Comment: Are you looking for `removeRowSelectionInterval()`? Why not use the model? It holds the data, and it will notify the table of the change; `updateComponentTreeUI` is not appropriate for this.

Comment: can you please help me with table model.I am having problem using it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your table model.

Comment: ((DefaultTableModel)searchListTable.getModel()).removeRow(selIndex);

Comment: ((DefaultTableModel)searchListTable.getModel()).removeRow(selIndex); I have used this now. But it is asking for integer type..and selIndex is String array.

Comment: These [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20removeRow) may guide you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete a row without using a TableModel: the `JTable` component doesn't hold any data, it only displays it.

So, you have to use:

```
tableModel.removeRow()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((DefaultTableModel)searchListTable.getModel()).removeRow(selIndex);
```

That should be everything.. The model will fire an event and the UI will be repainted..